# How to update the variable list in the config file dynamically in to python exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python file that converted into exe using pyinstaller 
but i need to get the data from another file which is to be updated and without another pyinstaller execution it needed to be worked like getting a data from the config file to exe

`from configfile import variables`

`variables` that is loaded from the configfile.py file but after converting into exe i cant able to update configfile.py variables

any suggestion will be welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function from the python config file updated and loaded dynamically outside the environment of exe

```
import os
extDataDir = os.getcwd()
ext_config = os.path.join(extDataDir, '', 'configfile.py')


def importCode(code,name,add_to_sys_modules=0):
    import sys,imp

    module = imp.new_module(name)

    exec(code,module.__dict__)
    if add_to_sys_modules:
        sys.modules[name] = module

    return module

configfile_rd = open(ext_config, "r")
configfile_code = configfile_rd.read()
configfile = importCode(configfile_code,"configfile") #dynamically readed the config file from exe and execute the python file configfile.py and working as well as import configfile

constant = configfile.variables()
```